# F# How do I access a member from a function

Tags: function, f#, member

I'm pretty new to F# so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here
here's what I'm trying to do:

```
type MyClass() =
    let someVar = this.MyMember()

    member this.MyMember() :unit = 
        // insert some code here
```

I can't do that because Visual Studio tells me that "this" isn't defined
so what should I do?
am I missing some obvious feature of F# or something?

I tried making all my members functions instead... but then I'd have to re-order all the functions so they become visible and then it still wouldn't work

so what do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to insert a self-identifier.  This is not done by default for some performance reasons.

The following works:

```
type MyClass() as this =
    let someVar = this.MyMember()

    member this.MyMember() :unit = ()
```

Comment: "This is not done by default for some performance reasons"... that's interesting, could you elaborate or provide a reference that explains why?

Comment: @Asik - I don't know why but here is some relevant code and the warning it generates `type t() as self = class end;;
stdin(2,13): warning FS1183: The recursive object reference 'self' is unused. The presence of a recursive object reference adds runtime initialization checks to members in this and derived types. Consider removing this recursive object reference.`